# Extra integer in the output

Tags: c

I wrote a program which takes an integer and depending upon that number takes further action, like calculating Factorial, Fibonacci and Exiting the program. But there is something wrong with the code. When it calculates the Fibonacci or Factorial it shows random number in the last of output which is weird and I can't figure it out. Code and screenshot is below [image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int Menu(int num) {
    printf("Press 1 to calculate Factorial\n");
    printf("Press 2 to calculate Fibannaci series\n");
    printf("Press 0 to Quit\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
LOOP:
    if (num == 1) {
        int n;
        printf("Enter the number whose Factorial you wanna calculate: " );
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("%d", Fact(n));
    } else
    if (num == 2) {
        int n;
        printf("Enter the term whose Fibannaci series you wanna calculate: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("%d", Fib(n));
    } else
    if (num == 0) {
        printf("Program is Quitting!");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        while (num < 0 ^ num > 2) {
            printf("Enter Correct number: ");
            scanf("%d", &num);
        }
        goto LOOP;
    }
}

int Fact(int n) {
    int Factorial;
    if (n == 1 || n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        Factorial = n * Fact(n - 1);
    }
}

int Fib(int n) {
    int Fibonacci;
    if (n <= 1) {
        return n;
    } else {
        Fibonacci = Fib(n - 1) + Fib(n - 2);
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("%d", Menu(1));
}
```

Comment: @LeeTaylor He just learns :)

Comment: 1) Poste text as text, not images. 2) Format & indent the code properly; it is unreadable. 3) `goto` has its usages. But not for this problem! 4) See [ask].

Answer (score 3):

The "extra" output is because you are printing the return value of `Menu()` (but it doesn't return one). This is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What happens is that `printf()` prints 120 (`printf("%d", Fact(n));`) for your chosen input of 5  and its return value (the number of chars printed) is 3, which is printed by the `printf()` in main(). But don't rely on this as this is just en explanation of what happens in your case and by no means a guarantee. As said before, your code has undefined behaviour.

If you don't have the need to return a value from `Menu()`, you can just make it a `void` function.

---

There are more problems that I initially found. Compiling your code, GCC reports:

```
test.c: In function ‘Menu’:
test.c:12:18: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Fact’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     printf("%d", Fact(n));
                  ^
test.c:18:18: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Fib’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     printf("%d", Fib(n));
                  ^
test.c:22:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘exit’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     exit(0);
     ^
test.c:22:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
test.c:22:5: note: include ‘<stdlib.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘exit’
test.c:26:14: warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of ‘^’ [-Wparentheses]
     while(num<0 ^ num>2){
              ^
test.c: In function ‘Fact’:
test.c:36:9: warning: variable ‘Factorial’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int Factorial;
         ^
test.c: In function ‘Fib’:
test.c:46:9: warning: variable ‘Fibinnaci’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int Fibinnaci;
         ^
test.c: In function ‘Menu’:
test.c:33:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
test.c: In function ‘Fact’:
test.c:43:2: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  }
  ^
test.c: In function ‘Fib’:
test.c:53:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

1) You are calling `Fact()` and `Fib()` before compiler could their declarations. You can fix it by declaring at the top:

```
int Fact(int);
int Fib(int);
```

2) You haven't included `stdlib.h>` for `exit()`'s prototype.

3) Not returning anything for inputs other than `1` or `0` from `Fact()` and `Fib()` functions. You can fix this by returning values from the `else` parts:

```
 else {
     return n* Fact(n-1);
 }
```

and

```
else {
    return Fib(n-1)+ Fib(n-2);
}
```

Comment: `Fact()` function doesn't  have `return`. 120 seems to be garbage as well

Comment: I didn't write any return statement. Can you tell me exactly what should i write to print Factorial of 5?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Right. Seems the same problem is there in `Fib()` too!

Comment: @M.Samiullah You need to make your `Fib()` and `Fact()` return a value for any input other than 0 and 1.

Comment: Actually, the `1203` is concatenation of 2 garbage value. Can be 1 and 203 also

Answer (score 1):

You could change the factorial function as:

```
int Fact(int n){

    if(n==1 || n==0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
     return n* Fact(n-1);
     }


 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the big help, i got it :)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in some other languages, the return value is produced in the function code by the `return` statement.  You `Fib` and `Fact` functions are incorrect, as the compiler would underscore with warnings if invoked with the appropriate flags (such as `gcc -Wall`).

Here is a corrected version:

```
int Fact(int n) {
    if (n == 1 || n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return n * Fact(n - 1);
    }
}

int Fib(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return Fib(n - 1) + Fib(n - 2);
    }
}
```

Since the functions weren't returning anything for the general case, `printf` was printing whatever value happens to be in the register that would normally be set with the return value.  This is a form of undefined behavior: anything ca happen, trying to interpret the observed behavior is useless.

Furthermore, you should output a linefeed after the number:

```
printf("%d\n", Fact(n));
```

Note also that the condition in `while (num < 0 ^ num > 2)` is probably not what you meant: the operator for logical OR is written `||`.  The `^` is the bitwise exclusive or operator.

```
while (num < 0 || num > 2)
```